# in jsf how to store radio buttons into a bean

Tags: java, jsf-2

please write the bean for this code:

```
<h:dataTable rows="10" value="#{LoginFormBean.keyAsList}"
        rendered="true" var="deviceid" id="producten">
        <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{deviceid}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:selectOneRadio value="#{LoginFormBean.deviceMap[deviceid]}">
                <c:if test="#{LoginFormBean.deviceMap[deviceid] eq ON}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="ON" itemLabel="ON" />
                </c:if>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="OFF" itemLabel="OFF" />
                </c:otherwise>
            </h:selectOneRadio>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>

    <h:commandButton value="submit"
        action="#{LoginFormBean.updateConfigurations}" />
```

here devicemap contains deviceid as key and status is the value
after submiting the button values has to store..how my bean will look like please help me..

Comment: How much you pay for an hour? ;)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaqm.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to save in pojo class.

Answer (score 0):

```
// imports

@ManagedBean   // or @Named
@SessionScoped // the scope you want
public class LoginFormBean implements Serializable{
    private List<Object> keyAsList;
    private HashMap<String, String> deviceMap;

    public LoginFormBean() {
        this.keyAsList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        this.deviceMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }

    //getters - setters

    public void updateConfigurations() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Something like this. You should read [How to write a managedBean](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.jsf.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Ftasks%2Fcreate_managedbean.html).